# b64toBlob() just returns size and type instead of full image data

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

Here is my b64toBlob() function which I'm using for converting base64 to blob so I'll be able to upload it into the server by appending to a formData:

```
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
    return blob;
}
```

and Here is my base64 code:

```
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
```

But when I run it, it just returns `Blob(15598) {size: 15598, type: "image/jpeg"}` without image data.

**---- Update:**
I'm sure It's not an error about back-end (because I'm using the same API in other components for upload) but, here is the rest of my code:

(I'm using react and 'that' is equal to this)

```
...

                                            var myDURL = c.toDataURL('image/jpeg')
                                            var base64result = myDURL.split(',')[1];
                                            var theblob = that.b64toBlob(base64result, 'image/jpeg')

                                            var photosformdata = new FormData()
                                            photosformdata.append('files', theblob);

                                            let authUserID = await localStorage.getItem('usrid')
                                            let filesResult = await requester(config.serverurl + 'v1/panel/users/' + await authUserID + '/profile/avatar', 'PUT', true, null, photosformdata, true)
                                            if (filesResult.statusCode == 200 || filesResult.statusCode == 201) {
                                                console.log(filesResult)
                                                this.props.actions.setUploadedFilesOnAddNewMedia(filesResult.data.filesArray)
                                            }
...
```

and here is in down below: (first one is what am I getting and secound one is what am I had to get):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, EVERYTHING works fine and good as expected! I just missed a name for my file on *formData.append()*

I just added a name for it as down below:

```
photosformdata.append('files', theblob, 'image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of the blob is not displayed in the console. Use [`FilerReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader):

```
var b = b64toBlob(b64, 'image/jpeg')

var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', (e) => {
  console.log(e.srcElement.result);
});

fileReader.readAsText(b);
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/srL845g7/ ]

Comment: Considering that when I'm sending it to the server, the server can't parse it and find image data to upload, I think the problem isn't there...

Comment: The function works correctly. It means an error or in the way you send the file to the server. Or on the server.

Comment: But I just simply put b64toBlob into a variable and got console.log from it. before than sending it to server

Comment: It's really confusing  :((

Comment: How do you send data to the server? Which server do you use?